# How can I select a storyboard element without selecting elements I don't want to select?

Tags: xcode, layout, uistoryboard

Whenever I try to click on an element to drag in this project, I accidentally drag elements I didn't want to drag instead.

[image]

Comment: Good question, but I think that this is by design. The developers/UX designers of Xcode must have thought that people want to select and drag a new item more often than they would drag the already selected item. BTW, if you want to position a view more precisely, use the arrow keys or the Size inspector.